# bash - escape character to take string as is

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following script in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
PSQL="psql -a -e -d users -U postgres --no-align -F$'\t' -c"
FILENAME="file.ext"
QUERY="select * from users limit 1;"
${PSQL} "${QUERY}" # > ${FILENAME}
```

But the `-F$'\t'` is evaluated differently. How can we make sure that the string will not be evaluated to return a different string, i.e. finally we would like to execute the command as: `psql -a -e -d users -U postgres --no-align -F$'\t' -c "select * from users limit 1;" > file.ext`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve your problem is to use arrays:

```
PSQL=( psql -a -e -d users -U postgres --no-align $'-F\t' -c )
FILENAME="file.ext"
QUERY="select * from users limit 1;"
"${PSQL[@]}" "${QUERY}" # > ${FILENAME}
```

**Explanation.** The first line defines a new array named PSQL. You can think of it as:

```
PSQL[0] = psql
PSQL[1] = -a
PSQL[2] = -e
PSQL[3] = -d
PSQL[4] = users
PSQL[5] = -U
PSQL[6] = postgres
PSQL[7] = --no-align
PSQL[8] = -F<tab>
PSQL[9] = -c
```

In the last line, the (double-quoted) term `"${PSQL[@]}"` will expand to the 10 "words" that constitute the array `PSQL` and the (double-quoted) term `"${QUERY}"` will expand to the string `select * from users limit 1;` considered a single word. To make things clearer, I'm going to show you how the expansion works using `{` and `}` to group each argument bash sees when expanding the line `"${PSQL[@]}" "${QUERY}"`:

```
{ psql } { -a } { -e } { -d } { users } { -U } { postgres } { --no-align } { -F<tab> } { -c } { select * from users limit 1; }
```

**Remark.** Using all upper-case variable names in `bash` is considered bad practice.

Comment: i just want to escape it. how can it be done?! no need to advance tricks to get simple thing working :)

Comment: @MrRoth This is not advanced and absolutely not a trick. It's only good bash practice.

Comment: @MrRoth The sad thing is that you didn't take the chance to learn good practices from experienced guys.

Comment: @MrRoth: The shell replaces variables (e.g. `${PSQL}`) *after* it has evaluated escapes, quotes, etc. Therefore, any escapes, quotes, etc in the replacement string will have no effect. There is literally no way to do this the way you want to. See [BashFAQ #050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure

- that the tab character is actually stored in the string:

```sh
 PSQL="psql -a -e -d users -U postgres --no-align -F"$'\t'" -c"
```

- that bash does not ignore the tab during evaluation:

```sh
OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS=" "
${PSQL} "${QUERY}" # > ${FILENAME}
IFS="$OLDIFS"
```

The `IFS` (Internal field separator) is used by bash to separate individual parameters, and contains the tab character by default. You can verify that by typing `od -abc <<< "$IFS"`.

Comment: Playing with `IFS` in this case is not really the best option. The problem is solved with arrays, without any side effects whatsoever, and will work in much more general situations.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf You're answering a question that wasn't asked. The question was clearly about string evaluation.

Comment: I am answering the question "finally we would like to execute the command as: `psql -a -e -d users -U postgres --no-align -F$'\t' -c "select * from users limit 1;" > file.ext`"

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf That's right, but in my opinion, part of the problem is understanding why the original approach fails.

Answer (score -2):

solution is pretty simple, just chance the last line to:

```
eval "${PSQL} '${QUERY}' # > ${FILENAME}"
```

Comment: `eval` is evil, especially when it's useless.

Comment: complex syntax without any explanation is EVIL!

Comment: I've edited my answer a bit, if you need a point to be clarified, please ask in the comments. I'm not too sure what you find "complex" as I don't know what your bash background is.